# Cannot run Eclipse: bad constant type in NatureManager clas

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I cannot run Eclipse, due to this error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Signature index 405 in LocalVariableTable has bad constant type in class file org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/NatureManager
```

I am not sure of any changes in my system since last time I could run Eclipse (last week).

I am pointing to the same Java 8 VM (*-vm* argument in *eclipse.ini*), and there were no updates in the Eclipse installation neither.

The affected JARs should is `org.eclipse.core.resources_3.11.1.v20161107-2032.jar`.

I am a bit clueless now: any suggestion?

Comment: Which release of Eclipse is this? The current one?

Comment: nope, kind of old: Neon. I just rebooted and the problem disappeared. I don't know if this is eligible as an answer